# Why does sp hybridised orbital have more directional character than p orbital?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, orbitals, hybridization

It states so in my textbook. But since s orbital is non directional, shouldn't sp hybridized orbital be less directional in character than p orbital?

Comment: Yeah.. Seems your book is wrong here

Comment: It a "free" use of the term "direction", but it conveys the message especially if bond formed by it is foretoken. Just to say it a not precise term. I liked the answer by @amanasci

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Ignore everything else in image , this image is just for shape comparison.

As you can see in image that so orbital is a lobe with unsymmetrical shape this leads to its more directionality.

P orbital possess equal Electron Density on both sides of the orbital , but in case of sp orbital electron density isn't equal and that's the reason why sp is more directional than p .

That's also the reason for their different Electronegativity.

Comment: [The image](https://images.slideplayer.com/27/9215045/slides/slide_8.jpg) appears to be plagiarized from [this presentation, slide 8](https://slideplayer.com/slide/9215045/). You also might want to edit your illustrations instead of asking the reader to ignore a part of it. There is no white space before punctuation marks, and please use proper capitalization and consistent notations (e.g. don't mix up "P" and "p" for a p orbital).